# Find the values of $a$ and $b$ which make the following function continuous at $x = 2$

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

$$
g(x) = \begin{cases}
  \dfrac{x^3 + 7}{x^2+1} & \text{if $x < 2$} \\[4px]
  a & \text{if $x = 2$} \\[8px]
  b\cos(3(x-2)) & \text{if $x > 2$}
\end{cases}
$$

I know that for a function to be continuous, the limit must be the same, regardless of the direction from which we approach.

$$\lim_{x \to 2^-} g(x) = b\cos(3(2-2)) = b$$

Therefore, for the function to be continuous, we require: 
$b = 5/3 = a$.

Is my reasoning and solution correct? If not, please explain what I am doing wrong and how I can reason about a correct solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Check [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for formatting tips.

Comment: You have to use the $y\cdot b\cos$ argument. If anyone asks you $y$, you tell them $b\cos$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to piece together the function, so that the ends meet at $x=2$.

Thus,

$$a=\lim_{x\rightarrow 2}\left[\frac{x^3+7}{x^2+1}\right]=\frac{8+7}{4+1}=3$$

and

$$3=\lim_{x\rightarrow 2}[b\cos(3(x-2))]=b\cos 0=b.$$

So $a=b=3.$

Comment: Lovsovs, my apologies. There was an error in the question. :( Sorry again!

Comment: @ThePointer No worries mate! :)

Comment: Oh my goodness, I had an arithmetic error. What is wrong with me today! So For the function to be continuous, we require a = b = 3?

Comment: @ThePointer Yes. You can check this by inserting $x=2$ into all three functions (although the second doesn't depend on $x$, but still); they should all give the same.